# redux - same data fetch HOC component called multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a React decorator component which is connected to the Redux store and I'm using it to dispatch an action (which is used to get some data from an API endpoint) and show a Loader Component. Then, once the data is fetched, it shows a wrapped component.

It looks like this:

```js
const loadData = LoaderComponent => WrappedComponent => {
  class loadDataHOC extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      const {fetchData, isLoading} = this.props;

      if(!isLoading){
        fetchData();
      }
    }

    render() {
      const {data, isLoading} = this.props;

      if (isLoading) {
        return <LoaderComponent />;
      }

      return <WrappedComponent data={data} />;
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      data: getData(state),
      isLoading: getIsLoading(state)
    };
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({getData}, dispatch);

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(loadDataHOC);
};

export default loadData;
```

This component is meant to be reusable so I can use it to fetch and store the same data from different presentational components. What I'd like to do now is to use this component in two different parts of the **same view**, like this:

```js
const EnhancedComponent1 = loadData(Spinner)(MyPresentationalComponent1);
const EnhancedComponent2 = loadData(Spinner)(MyPresentationalComponent2)
```

The problem is that the two EnhancedComponent both fire `fetchData()` because they are mounted together and therefore the `isLoading` prop is `false` in both the function calls.

For now I've solved it by checking the `isLoading` prop inside the action so the second call is immediately stopped, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to deal with it.

```js
const getData = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  if(getIsLoading(getState())) {
    return;
  }

  dispatch(getData());
  ...
};
```

Another way to do it would be to create only one parent enhanced component just to fetch the data and then two presentational components down the tree that only access the state, but I'd like to fetch the data as close as possible to the presentational component.

Thanks